# Удаление дубликатов в массиве объектов по уникальному ключу

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос такой: есть массив объектов, в каждом объекте находится еще несколько объектов, среди которых есть объект **caption** со свойством **id** (строка с цифрами), по значению которого идет сравнение. Нужно получить новый массив объектов без дубликатов по значению **id**. То есть если **temp[i].caption.id** равен **temp[j].caption.id**, то добавить в массив **result** только один объект, избавиться от повторений.

Исходный массив выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример исходного массива и результирующего

Comment: @AntonShchyrov исходный массив заполняется данными из запроса к api instagram, могу вставить изображение с исходным массивом. Результирующий изначально пустой